# how can I change the style dynamically without accessing the DOM using only javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dom

I have a form with multiple fields, I want to dynamically change the style (border) of the field based on user action I am changing the DOM style of the current and next field in the current field event handler as bellow, is there any other ways without changing the DOM and no jquery changing the style dynamically?

```
document.getElementById("xyz").style.borderColor = "#FFF";
document.getElementById("xyz").style.borderWidth = "2px";
```

Comment: Would you mind using jQuery? it'll be much easier.

Comment: You have to change DOM anyway

Comment: You could store the styles in CSS and alter class names on elements...

Comment: Are you referring to CSS pseudo classes like `:active` , `:focus` ?

Comment: On What event would you like to change the style ??

Comment: Why do you not want to change the DOM? E.g. using classes? Or is the only requirement to not change the `style` property of an element?

Comment: There is no need for jWeakling script, you can easily do this with JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set a `class` or `attribute` on all the elements you want to change, then `querySelectorAll` by either, then use a `forEach` loop and loop through the selected tags changing the `className` to whatever you want, which would dynamically change everything.

**Example:**

In the example code below I set a class `.style1` on all elements I want to select then I `querySelectorAll('.style')`, the loop through those selected elements changing the `className` to `.style2`, which changes the border color from the blue to red.

```js
init=()=>{
 //SELECT & BIND (CLICK) EVENT
 var tags = document.querySelectorAll('.style1');
 //LOOP THROUGH TAGS WITH CLASS (.style1) AND CHANGE TO (.style2)
 tags.forEach((o)=>o.className = "style2");
}
//ON DOCUMENT LOAD RUN INIT
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',init);
```

```css
.style1{
 border: 1px solid blue;
}
.style2{
 border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
 <form>
  <input type="email" class="style1">
  <input type="password" class="style1">
  <textarea class="style1"></textarea>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with classes. for example, you can have this class setting:

```
.error {
    color: red;
}
```

and just apply it to different elements using jQuery, like:

```
$(this).addClass('error');
```

That's what I do on my own projects. You can use JavaScript but jQuery makes it much easier and cleaner :)

Comment: addClass changes DOM

Comment: @AndrewParamoshkin of course, but you have to change **something**, don't you?

Comment: Beside that it - as already mentioned - will change the dom. Why should it be clearer then: `elm.classList.add('error');`? (Supported by Chrome 28+, Edge 12+ , IE 10+, Safari 7+) so the same as the [active browsers support](http://jquery.com/browser-support/) of jQuery (except the IE 9+).

Comment: @ItayGanor Sure, but its "without changing the DOM" in the question.